# I think I have original sketch of patent 47789 - Rag doll

Tags: search

Is there any worth to original patent sketches?   It is the same as show on your sight.
Design/Inventor by JB Gruelle , Doll, Application filled May 28 1915/ Patented Sept. 7, 1915